# creating a chloropleth of data science jobs in Germany with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, gis

Earlier I made a visualization of data science jobs across Germany in the form of a [bar chart](http://smatthewenglish.com/animated-journey/) with the x-axis being the name of the city.

Now I have the same data, but with the latitude and longitude and I want to use it to create a chloropleth such that the different locations, also in Germany, will become darker or lighter based on the number of jobs located there.

I've found a tutorial that has [a basic map of the 16 federal states of Germany](http://bl.ocks.org/oscar6echo/4423770).

Would it be possible to use my new data, [located here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/verbose-octo-rotary-phone/master/queryResults_0.csv), and that interactive map to render each of the federal states a different colour corresponding to the quantity of jobs located there?

Comment: do you need zoom or panning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're 100% set on using d3, you'll he some extra work to do. You can start with the [d3+leaflet tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/). I have had trouble in the past keeping the projections aligned if you move/zoom a lot.

My recommendation would be to use just leaflet. They have [an example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)  choropleth map that you can pull from.